# Why does "UPDATE Users SET Password=? WHERE Username=?" give a syntax error?

Tags: visual-studio

Using Visual Studio 2012

I had this SQL for updating an access database with correct naming of fields/parameters/etc

```
str = "UPDATE Users SET Password=? WHERE Username=?"
```

And I received a "syntax error in SQL statement" error.

Then, through some tinkering, I made this, which works:

```
str = "UPDATE Users SET Passwor=? WHERE Username=?"
```

My question is why will it not work if I use "Password" but will with "Passwor". I tried with several other fields and they all seem to work except "Password". Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Seems like the field you expect to be named "password" is actually named "passwor" ?

Comment: Sadly no, I wish it was that simple. Even if that was the case, surely it would be some sort of missing parameter error, not a syntax error.

Comment: Isn't "password" reserved in Access?  You might want to try `[Password]`.

Comment: Password is a reserved word, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: @Comintern - possibly but how would that explain "Passwor" working (unless it doesn't actually...)?

Comment: I really must be tired for not having noticed that, it worked and cheers for the help @Comintern.

Comment: Because `passwor" isn't a reserved word?  It isn't really clear what happened in the "through some tinkering, I made this, which works" step.  I'd assumed a field name change.

Comment: @Comintern - ah yes, I'd assumed the OP was just adjusting their SQL...

Comment: How do I mark this as answered?

Comment: Done and thanks again for the help.